# Rust - Get value from method without borrowing (count the lines of file)

Tags: rust, io, borrowing

I'm quite new in rust and I have no idea how to workaround.
The code is:

```
let input = File::open(file_path)?;
let buffered = BufReader::new(input);

let line_count = buffered.lines().count();

 for (nr, line) in buffered.lines().enumerate() {
    print!("\rLOADED: [{}/{}]", nr, line_count);
    // do something...
}
```

The error I've got:

```
let buffered = BufReader::new(input);
    -------- move occurs because `buffered` has type `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

let line_count = buffered.lines().count();
                 -------- value moved here
  
for (nr, line) in buffered.lines().enumerate() {
                  ^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

Please help, I'm stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `BufReader::new(file_handle);` consumes the `file_handle` and calling `buffered.lines()` consumes `buffered`. There might be a more efficient, clever, or elegant way to do this but you can open and iterate over the file twice if you want to first get the full line count:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file_path = "input.txt";
    let input = File::open(file_path)?;
    let buffered = BufReader::new(input);
    let line_count = buffered.lines().count();

    let input = File::open(file_path)?;
    let buffered = BufReader::new(input);
    for (nr, line) in buffered.lines().enumerate() {
        println!("LOADED: [{}/{}]", nr, line_count);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Yeap, I know I could just open and iterate over the file twice, as you have written, but I guess want to avoid such methods if it's possible.